# Extracting columns from a large text file

Tags: matlab, text

I am a novice with working with big data so hopefully there is a simple solution to the problem below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have been modifying a ~2GB text file with EmEditor which is 315,000x1706.  The header of each column contains a 1 or 2 randomly.  Here is a small picture of what I have:

```
1  2  2  1  1  1  2  1          1  1  1  1  1    2  2  2

AA TT TA CT TT GA TA CT         AA CT TT GA CT   TT TA TA  
AA TT TA CT TT GA TA CT         AA CT TT GA CT   TT TA TA
AA TT TA CT TT GA TA CT         AA CT TT GA CT   TT TA TA 
       (File)                       (File 1)     (File 2)
```

I need to break this into two files, one with only the "1" columns and another with only the "2" columns.

Any suggestions on how to do this?  The file is too large to open in excel.  This data will eventually end up in Matlab.  Could this be accomplished using Matlab?

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to achieve what you want for smaller text files? With a text file, you basically have to read it line by line and process it.

Comment: Even with smaller files I don't know where to begin with this.

Comment: I assume that there are multiple rows along the lines of `AA TT TA CT TT GA TA CT`? It would be helpful if you edited the question to provide a more complete mini-example of what is in the file.

Comment: Edited to show what I need to do.  In a simple example I would just copy and paste each column with it's respective header but I have 1706 columns and cannot manually do this.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have tons of memory or do you want to be memory efficient?

Comment: I have 32GB RAM.  Would that be enough?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) to read the data and [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) to write it:

```
% Read data
f0 = 'data0.txt';
fid = fopen(f0,'r');
head = textscan(fid,'%u');
data = textscan(fid,'%2s');
fclose(fid);

% Process data
idx = (head{1}==1);
data = reshape(data{1},numel(idx),[]);

% Write file corresponding to 1s in header
f1 = 'data1.txt';
fid = fopen(f1,'w+');
fprintf(fid,[repmat('%s ',1,nnz(idx)-1) '%s\n'],data{idx,:});
fclose(fid);

% Write file corresponding to 2s in header
f2 = 'data2.txt';
fid = fopen(f2,'w+');
fprintf(fid,[repmat('%s ',1,nnz(~idx)-1) '%s\n'],data{~idx,:});
fclose(fid);
```

The only potential issue with the above is that you might have memory issue if your files are sufficiently large.

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a shot this weekend.  The machine I'm working with has 32GM RAM.  Otherwise I will split the files up.  Thanks again!